# Find minimum steps to reach the end of graph

Tags: c++, graph

Given a directed graph which has nodes from 1 to N where each node has a color(blue/red) which is given to us. Now nodes are connected and each edge has some weight. We have to reach N from 1 such that in the path abs(x-y)<=k where x is the number of red nodes and y is the number of blue nodes and k is some integer value.

I tried solving using the Dijkstra shortest path algorithm but that will work only when there is no condition on no. of blue and red balls. So how should things proceed with Dijkstra or this requires something else?

Comment: Hint: A graph search algorithm explores the reachable states. Suppose you can get to node X having crossed mostly red balls, and you can also get to node X having crossed mostly blue balls. In either case you're in the same *place*, but are you in the same *state*?

Comment: Djikstra's optimisation that the first path to reach a node is the cheapest only really works if all the link costs are >=0. If this is not the case, then consider other techniques.

Comment: If your graph does not have negative loops, you can use [Bellman Ford](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm). You just use a weight of 1 for edge from red to blue, -1 for blue to red and 0 for the others.

Comment: @Pierre-NicolasMougel But the edges are already weighted, are you adding 1 or subtracting 1 from the already present weight of edge?

Comment: Build a small graph and try simple arithmetic operation. I am sure you will find the answer.